# Bluetooth Socket becomes null when trying to close it (Error: null object reference)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

My app has a MainActivity.java which initializes 2 buttons (btnBTConnect and btnBTStop) and calls setOnClickListener methods for them.

In BluetoothActivity.java, I have the onClick methods which call the methods. For btnBTConnect it calls my methods to find the bluetooth device (findBT), connect to it and receive the inputStream (openBT). For btnBTStop, it calls my method to close the connection (closeBT).

When I click the start bluetooth button, I have no problem. The connection is made and data is received as expected (BluetoothSocket and InputStream are NOT null).

However, when I click the bluetooth Stop button, to stop the data and close the InputStream and Socket, I get a null object reference error.

Can someone please help? Is it because of how I have the onClick setup? By using switch and case, are all my variables from the findBT  and openBT methods removed when it switches to the bluetooth stop case? Is that why my Bluetooth Socket and InputStream are null when I try to close them?

How can I fix this?

Thanks

MainAcitivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

public Button btnBTConnect;
public Button btnBTStop;
BluetoothAdapter mBTAdap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBTAdap = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    btnBTConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnBTConnect);
    btnBTStop = findViewById(R.id.btnBTStop);
    btnBTConnect.setOnClickListener(new BluetoothActivity(getApplicationContext()));
    btnBTStop.setOnClickListener(new BluetoothActivity(getApplicationContext()));
}
```

BluetoothActivity

```
public class BluetoothActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final String TAG = "BluetoothActivity";
Context mContext;
public BluetoothAdapter mBTAdap;
public BluetoothSocket mBTSock;
public BluetoothDevice mBTDev;
public InputStream mBTIP;
public Thread mBTThread;
byte[] mBuffer;
volatile boolean mStopThread;

public BluetoothActivity(Context myContext) {
    this.mBTAdap = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    this.mContext = myContext;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View mView) {
    switch (mView.getId()){
        case R.id.btnBTConnect:
            try {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            } catch (IOException e) {Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + e.getMessage(), e);}
            break;
        case R.id.btnBTStop:
            try {
                closeBT();
            } catch (IOException e) {Log.e(TAG, "onClick: " + e.getMessage(), e);}
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void findBT() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> mBTPairedDevices = mBTAdap.getBondedDevices();
    if (mBTPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : mBTPairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals("myDevice")) {
                mBTDev = device;
                toastMessage(mBTDev.getName() + " device found");
                break;
            } else {toastMessage("No device found");}
        }
    } else {toastMessage("No Devices paired");}

}

public void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID mUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    try {
        mBTSock = mBTDev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "openBT: " + e.getMessage(), e); toastMessage("Couldn't create RFComm socket");}
    mBTSock.connect();
    mBTIP = mBTSock.getInputStream();
    listenBT();
}

public void listenBT(){
    mStopThread = false;
    mBuffer = new byte[6];

    mBTThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !mStopThread) {
                try {
                    bytes = mBTIP.read(mBuffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    mStopThread = true;
                    Log.e(TAG, "run: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    }); mBTThread.start();
}

public void closeBT() throws IOException {
    mStopThread = true;
    mBTIP.close();
    mBTSock.close();

    toastMessage("BT Closed");
    Log.d(TAG, "closeBT: BT Closed");
}

private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Logcat

```
02-06 19:54:41.256 3915-3915/com.example.mark.btconnflow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.mark.btconnflow, PID: 3915
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.close()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.mark.btconnflow.BluetoothActivity.closeBT(BluetoothActivity.java:202)
                                                                           at com.example.mark.btconnflow.BluetoothActivity.onClick(BluetoothActivity.java:79)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: if(mBTSock!=null) mBTSock.close();

Comment: DO this, while closing.

Comment: `mBTSock` can't become `null` on its own. Something must be happening to the Activity so that it gets recreated. If you're going for a quick fix do `if (mBTSock != null) mBTSock.close()`, but that doesn't ensure that the socket is closed.

Comment: I have tried if(mBTSock!=null) mBTSock.close(). Before I click the stop button, it is n't null. But once I click the stop button, it is always null when I enter the closeBT method. Even though it keeps receiving data, so it can't be null?

Comment: There can be a case when the socket does not get initialised due to some exception, but later on same is being closed. I thing there logs preceding the error should also be checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make two different objects and put them in listeners. Try with:

```
    BluetoothActivity listener = new BluetoothActivity(getApplicationContext());
    btnBTConnect.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btnBTStop.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a million for the quick answer.